# How to edit list inside loop and update rows based on Python condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a dataframe that looks like the below: what I am trying to do is loop through and identify rows that have a specific condition. The condition is looking for values that are greater than or equal to 10 and where Col1 and Col2 are not the same.

After identifying that, I then need to take the values that matched that criteria and replace values in Col1 with values from Col2.

Before:

```
Col1,  Col2,  Col3
entry  Test   10
entry  entry  10
entry  Phase  3
entry  Non_e  10
Non_e  Test   12
Test   Non    12
Phase  Non    12
Non    Pair   12
```

After: (Desired Result)

```
Col1,  Col2,  Col3
entry  Test   10  
entry  entry  10  
entry  Phase  3   
entry  Non_e  10  
entry  Test   12  
entry  Non    12
Phase  Non    12
Phase  Pair   12
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't use loops in pandas. Instead leverage pandas to get the result that you want.

Comment: "The condition is looking for values that are greater than or equal to 10" Which values? I assume those in `Col3`, but want to confirm.

Comment: Yes it is looking for those values in Col3, that is correct.

Comment: Your description doesn't seem to match the provided example result. For example, why is the first row not modified, and where does the 'Phase' come from in the last row? To select rows matching your description you can use special indexing like so: `df.loc[(df.Col1 != df.Col2) & (df.Col3 >= 10)]`

Comment: What it was trying to show as as I loop through the dataframe using something like itertuples() it first checks to see if Col3 is >= 10 and if Col1 and Col2 are not the same. If that criteria matches then it will replace what was found in Col2 with what was in Col1 for all of Col1. So for the first record it finds Test, then it would loop through Col1 and replace "Test" with "Entry" and so on and so forth. I hope that helped clarify a little bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- as per comments - no looping required, plus looping is an anti-pattern in **pandas**
- just need a mask that matches your condition.  Can then apply your operations to rows that match the condition

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""Col1  Col2  Col3
entry  Test   10
entry  entry  10
entry  Phase  3
entry  Non_e  10
Non_e  Test   12
Test   Non    12
Phase  Non    12
Non    Pair   12"""), sep="\s+")


cond = df["Col3"].ge(10) & (df["Col1"]!=df["Col2"])
df.loc[cond] = df.loc[cond].assign(Col1=df.loc[cond,"Col2"], Col2=df.loc[cond,"Col1"])
```

#### output

|  | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Test | entry | 10 |
| 1 | entry | entry | 10 |
| 2 | entry | Phase | 3 |
| 3 | Non_e | entry | 10 |
| 4 | Test | Non_e | 12 |
| 5 | Non | Test | 12 |
| 6 | Non | Phase | 12 |
| 7 | Pair | Non | 12 |

Comment: I am very new to Python, so I appreciate the advice on not looping in Pandas. However, the output I would want would be as the conditions were met then it would change the values that were found in Col2 in Col1. So for the first row, "Test" is found and it met our criteria. I would then want it to change all values of "Test" to "entry" in Col1 if that is even possible and just continue to do that as it worked its way through the dataframe. I guess that is why I assumed I would need a loop

Comment: misread you question so used `> 10` instead of `>=10` as condition.  Updated now behaves as you have stated

Comment: So if I have an excel calculation that is doing what I want, would you be able to decipher it into Python code? I know that sounds super clunky but I dont know how else to explain. Here is the calculation if its still something someone can help with, if needed I can restructure the question "=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(A2,C:C,0))"